# How to resolve The web/application server is leaking version information via the "Server" HTTP response header?

Tags: wcf, zap

`Currently we are using ZAP tool to find all vulnerabilities that WCF service  have . I ran the zap  tool for WCF service then we found security alerts like  "The web/application server is leaking version information via the "Server" HTTP response header"?

Does someone know, what configuration changes I need to do ?

Answer (score 1):

1.I think you can program the security of WCF to be secure.
Generally speaking, we have security settings on the bindings of the service.

```
<system.serviceModel>  
<bindings>  
  <wsHttpBinding>  
    <binding name="myBinding">  
      <security mode="Message"/>  
      <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>  
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>  
</system.serviceModel>
```

There are three modes of this: **Transport**, **Message**, **TransportWithMessageCredential**.

You can also write in code：

```
WSHttpBinding b = new WSHttpBinding();
b.Name = "myBinding";
b.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
b.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType=MessageCredentialType.Windows;
```

You can browse the Microsoft documentation below for more information：

[Programming WCF Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/programming-wcf-security)

2.Secondly, you can also explore Microsoft's solutions for WCF information leakage,
It illustrates a number of solutions.

[Information Disclosure](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/information-disclosure)

Best Regards